# Winforms Document Viewer Component

Tags: .net, winforms, components

I'm doing maintenance on a Winforms application. They are in need of a 'preview' for different file types:

- Word (.docx / .doc)
- Excel (.xlsx / .xls)
- PDF
- Email (.eml)

These documents are stored as blobs in a database, so ideally, I would just be able to pass a stream or a byte[] to the component, without storing it to a temp folder first.

Is there a viewer (commercially) available that will suit these needs?

It's not that I can't find viewer components, but most of them aren't 100% clear about what file types they can and cannot handle, and how they can receive input. Most code samples just read a file from disk.

Comment: If you want to keep some of your hair, you should consider copying those blop as a file in a temp folder and use a good old process.start to open these file with the corresponding application. Don't forget to add some "magic" to clean the temporary files.

Comment: We're not trying to open the corresponding editors, we just want a view of the file (like a print preview). Preferably without leaving our application.